# What happened to Bon Clay after the Impel Down arc?

Tags: one-piece

**SPOILER ALERT: Contains spoilers for those who have not read or watched the end of Impel Down arc.**

In the anime episode 451, Bon Clay disguises himself as Magellan to help Luffy and the prisoners escape on the Marine ship. Magellan gets very angry when he finds out, and attacks Bon Clay.

[image: Magellan ready to attack Bon Clay]

The episode ends after a few seconds, and the subsequent episodes do not show what happened next. Does it imply that Bon Clay was killed offscreen, or is this left as a suspense?

Answer (score 16):

Bon Clay did not get killed. He somehow survived the fight against Magellan, and escaped to the Level 5.5 (Newkamaland), where he has become the new "Queen". Many of the Newkama prisoners who escaped during the Impel Down arc have reoccupied it.

The canonical evidence is on the cover page of Chapter 666. It is not yet known how Bon Clay escaped from Magellan, or how and why the Newkama prisoners returned to Impel Down.

[image: Chapter 666 cover page]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I really thought he was dead. Glad to hear that he is alive. :)

Comment: You should at least wait for someone to answer. LOL

Comment: @NixR.Eyes I wanted to share this information with the community. Since SE works only in Q&A mode (there's no "blog" option), I had to post it in a "Answer Your Own Question" format.

Comment: @Happy No, I dont mean it that way. It just happens that I love Bon Clay's role in the Impel Down Arc. And it saddened me too that he has to sacrifice himself at the end, then glad to find out that he is alive. =)

Comment: @NixR.Eyes Yeah, I love him too. For me, Bon Clay (not Luffy) was the real hero of the Impel Down arc. Don't think Luffy would complain. ;) Many of my friends who only watch anime were depressed that he died, so I thought I should share this to spread some happiness. :)

Comment: Wow, even i had no clue about it!
But is he so strong that he could actually survive Magellan!!?

Comment: @MärmîkŠhâh May not be strong enough to defeat Magellan, but he is a master of disguise. He might have deceived Magellan *again* to escape.

Comment: Ya, man i would love to see him back in the anime!!

Comment: It's just a speculation, but as we know Magellan was defeated by the Blackbeard pirates. With a lucky timing that could be the cause why he survived. But as I said, this is just a speculation.